# check an existing data if not then create mongodb and monggose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to do a pre-existence check on the MongoDB data and if does not exist then insert, but somehow I am not able to perform that. When I did a console log at the express, it did capture the data but somehow it didn't work. Here is my model and the rest API:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {ObjectID} = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const ScheduleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    startdate: {type: Date},
    enddate: {type: Date},
    dateadded: {type: Date,default: Date.now},
    userid:[{type:ObjectID, ref:"User"}],
  },{ timestamps: true });
  
  module.exports = mongoose.model("Schedule", ScheduleSchema)
```

The API:

```
const Schedule = require('../models/schedules')


router.post('/schedule/addschedule/:id',JWTAuthenticatToken, async (req, res) => {   
   const{startdate,enddate} = req.body

    //the console log did print out the data
    //{
    //startdate: '2021-04-05T06:27:40.000Z',
    //enddate: '2021-04-08T16:00:00.000Z'
    //}
    //6055e1ed5eec1e1c10df91d4

   console.log(req.body)
   console.log(req.params.id)

    const existingSchedule = await Schedule.find({startdate: startdate,enddate:enddate,userid:req.params.id})
    if(existingSchedule){
        return res.json({statusCode: "409", msg:'This schedule already exisits!'});
    }else{
        const schedule = new Schedule({
            startdate: startdate,
            enddate:enddate,
            userid:existingSchedule.req.params.id})            
            const scheduleresult = await schedule.save()
            return res.json({statusCode: "200"})
    }
});
```

I am wondering where did I go wrong? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

> Using the upsert option, you can use findOneAndUpdate() as a find-and-upsert operation. An upsert behaves like a normal findOneAndUpdate() if it finds a document that matches the filter. But, if no document matches the filter, MongoDB will insert one by combining filter and update as shown below.

```
doc = await Schedule.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {
  new: true, // You should set the new option to true to return the document after update was applied.
  upsert: true // Make this update into an upsert
});
```